# Where the is "InvalidTag" coming from in ColdFusion?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-2016

Whenever Script tag is added in the input controls on a form after reloading these pages, I see it has become "InvalidTag". Where did it come from?

Comment: You'll need to provide more information.

Comment: from memory i think theres something in the cf admin that replaces certain html like the <script> tag and replaces with it with that invalid tag. you can turn off per application with <cfapplication name="appName" scriptProtect="none">

Comment: You would need to provide some code or more information, but I would lean towards what @luke wrote. However, be very careful if you turn that off. There’s a reason why a script tag inside a text input is an invalid tag because it protects you against JavaScript injection in user generated content, which is a hacking technique used to do all sorts of bad things to your site.

Comment: @luke is correct, There is a setting in the admin to protect against script attacks. That is what replaces the tags with "InvalidTag". Luke, you should add that as an answer to this question. Put some details in there about the setting too.

Comment: @luke, Thank you. I learnt it can be turned off per application as you mentioned. Also I found that there is another configuration xml present at "ColdFusionInstalledFolder\cfusion\lib\neo-security.xml", Under this they have placed a variable as `<var name='&lt;\s*(object|embed|script|applet|meta)'><string>&lt;InvalidTag</string></var>` which replaces any of "object|embed|script|applet|meta" these to InvalidTag.

Comment: VishwasSL - Either you or @luke should post the final solution as an answer.